# Find an element in a list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I have the following list of tuples.

```
[('rel', 'dns-prefetch'), ('href', 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com')]
[('rel', 'dns-prefetch'), ('href', 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com')]   
[('rel', 'dns-prefetch'), ('href', 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com')]
[('rel', 'dns-prefetch'), ('href', 'http://completion.amazon.com')]
[('rel', 'dns-prefetch'), ('href', 'http://fls-na.amazon.com')]
[('rel', 'stylesheet'), ('href', 'http://z-ecx.images-  amazon.com/images/G/01/AUIClients/NavAuiAssets-bc93e610a616dd196eda0cc0238d74dd3f830199.min._V2_.css')]
[('rel', 'stylesheet'), ('href', 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AUIClients/AmazonUI-c0d0f2a115191b947c48fd97b453a95d32cbadc0.rendering_engine-not-trident.weblab-AUI_CSS_REDUCTION_28708-T1.weblab-AUI_HIGH_CONTRAST_40800-T1.min._V2_.css')]
[('rel', 'stylesheet'), ('href', 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AUIClients/AmazonGatewayAuiAssets-0320163872407ddbb58566fd72a492fca3b17ed4.min._V2_.css')]
[('rel', 'canonical'), ('href', 'http://www.amazon.com/')]
```

I need to find an element in those. I am doing.

```
 for attr in attrs:
    #Need a code here to find an element without iterating over attar.
```

Is there a way to do that in Python.

Comment: whats the logic for find that element ?

Comment: Post some example so one can better understand the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` to test membership:

```
>>> for attr in attrs:
...   if ('href', 'http://fls-na.amazon.com') in attr:
...     print attr
...
[('rel', 'dns-prefetch'), ('href', 'http://fls-na.amazon.com')]
```